# viewWillDisappear network activity is causing jerk effect in UI

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsoperation

I'm performing network activity in `viewWillDisappear` event, this is causing a jerk(delay) in coming back animation, can I use `performSelectorWithDelay` for this network activity in my `viewWillDisappear` event? so that after my animation block completes network operation will start. Is that safe?

Comment: Please tell us how you're doing this network call, by posting some code. Is it asynchronous?

Comment: If you want to wait until the animation is complete, you should perform your request in `viewDidDisappear` rather.

Comment: @cyrille it is an asynchronous call, ya I want to wait until my animation gets completed.

Comment: Again, please post the code of your `viewWillDisappear` method.